# Facebook friends activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-fql

I have been using the Facebook API for the last couple of years, but this time I got stuck on this one. According to my one of application requirements, I need to get my Facebook friends' activities. What is the feasibility of this and the concerned APIs.

How do I get the number of counts and comments all included for a particular user's activity?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the real-time API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) to subscribe to a user's activity, for example, status updates, checkins, and likes.

All fields available to the real-time API from the user's object can be found in *[Core Concepts › Graph API › User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)*.

Comment: This is the correct way to handle the requirements stated in the question.  Good answer!!  :)  +1